# How to get the name of an object from a class in Python?

Tags: python, class, object

I know this is a weird idea. The idea would be something like this:

```
class AnyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        # print object name
```

Then create a new object

```
test = AnyClass()
```

And finally get this output:

```
'test'
```

That is not the idea behind this, but is an easy example of what I'm trying to...

PS: I'm not trying to get the class name, just the object name (if possible)
PS2: I know I can get the name with `test.__name__` but I'm trying to get the name inside the class, not outside.

Comment: You want the variable name that references to the object? How would the class know what variable it is assigned to?

Comment: Objects do not have names; names refer to objects.

Comment: `test` object does not exist at the time `AnyClass()` and as `test` does not exist when `__init__()` is called, I don't think there is a way for it to know its name.

Comment: @cricket_007 I don't know... I guess it is not possible :(

Comment: Local variable names are not stored anywhere except as references to memory locations within the Python interpreter; since these names are assigned memory locations at runtime, and Python has no meta-interpretive abstraction, I think this is not possible.

Comment: @licorna That's what I thought, but would fine to check the name of the object when it is created to check if the name follows some rules for example.

Comment: What if you have two variables referencing the same object?

Comment: I guess this would be possible by looping over locals looking for a reference to the class in question (optionally descending into containers) but whatever is making you think this is necessary, just rethink it.

Comment: what would you expect for `x= test = yellow = MyClass()` ?

Comment: This is almost certainly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Ask another question describing what you are actually trying to do.

Comment: The object name, at the place you have commented, is 'self' and that's the only name you need to know at that point

Answer (score 3):

Consider this:

```
>>> a = dict()
>>> b = a
```

Both `a` and `b` reference the exact same object.

```
>>> a is b
True
```

When you do a `.` operation on an object, you're looking up an attribute on that object.  An object can be referenced in many different locations; it makes no sense for it to store all those reference names, especially when those names are only bound within certain contexts.  For example

```
def generator():
    a = dict()
    yield a

b = next(generator())
```

Both `a` and `b` refer to the same `dict` object, but you can't use `a` to reference the `dict` anywhere else besides in the generator function.

Within a specific context, you can test the bound names and see if they refer to a specific object.

```
test = MyObject()

for name, obj in locals().items():
    if test is obj:
        print name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ^^

Answer (score 1):

First: you don't want to do this, there is no reason to do this, and if you think you need to do this, you're wrong.

Second: you can't do it in the `__init__` method because the name reference `test` referring to the new `AnyClass` instance object hasn't been added to the memory space ("bound") yet. However, you could do it like this.

```
class AnyClass():
    def echo_name(self):
        {v:k for k,v in locals().items()}[self]

test = AnyClass()
test.echo_name()
```

This will return the first variable encountered in the `locals()` dictionary that is assigned to the `test` object. There is no guarantee for the order in which those variables will be returned.

---

To explain a bit further about why it won't work in the `__init__` method, when you do this:

```
test = AnyClass()
```

A new instance of `AnyClass`is constructed according to the instructions of the class definition (including the definitions of any parent or metaclass). This construction happens in phases, the last phase of which is executing the `__init__` method. Prior to `__init__`, other methods that will be executed, if they exist, are `__new__`, and also the the `__new__`, `__init__`, and `__call__` methods of the metaclass (if one exists).

So at the point in time the code in the body of the `__init__` method is being executed, the object is still being constructed. Therefore there is, as of yet, nothing in the `locals()` dictionary assigned to the name `'test'`. There is only a member called `'self'`. And, obviously, if you reverse-lookup the `self` object in the `locals()` dictionary looking for a registered name, the name you will get is the name `'self'`. Which... isn't useful.

Comment: I think you mean `[self]`, not `[test]`.  This is supposed to be in the `__init__()` method.  I don't think that it will work anyway, though.

Comment: @zondo I missed that it is in the `__init__` method - you're right, won't even work.